# Why do i have to include JQuery again and if i do, other scripts stop working?

Tags: jquery, html

Why do i have to include jQuery again to make my code work if it is already somewhere else on the page?

Why if i include it again some parts of the website stop working?

The piece of jQuery i need to implement looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){    
    // Your code goes here    
        var clearedOnce = false;
        document.getElementById("telid01").onfocus = 
        function () {
            if (clearedOnce == false) {
                this.value = '';
                clearedOnce = true;
            }
        };
    });

</script>
```

So why do i have to include jQuery agan like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

on top of it to make it work?

Its also very strange because the code is at the very bottom of the page, just on top of

```
</body>
</html>
```

So there shouldn't be a problem with the rest of the page?

Comment: 1) You don't. 2) Version conflicts? Who knows? How could we tell?

Comment: can you please post your complete code, including HTML

Comment: Why don't you show us how you are including jquery

Comment: I don't know man, there has to be a way to solve this, I'm just learning jQuery and its very weird for me to have to include the same library again to make my script work and that if i do it messes up the rest of my site even if its at the end of it, don't you know any possible solution for this kind of issue? What could be causing it?

Comment: There, Huangism, i edited it.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: @Algorista: The code you've shown includes jQuery only once, so how can we possibly identify the issue?

Comment: Your browser has a JavaScript console where error messages are displayed. It should be a fundamental item in your tool-belt.

Comment: Okay im going to try with a new version of jQuery

Comment: Here is the complete code of the page in html http://pastebin.com/LrxW7aex

Comment: Okay i found some errors in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm...

`$(document).ready(function(){});` does not load jQuery all it does is add `function(){}` to the queue for when jQuery is ready (When the browser fires an event saying it's got all the content needed)

the only time you load jQuery is when you have the file loaded though the script tag E.G
`<script type="text/javascript"src="jQuery.js"></script>`

I have pages from a server built system that can have `$(document).ready(...` 4 or 5 times inside their content

If it's causing a problem. what is the problem from the Console in your browser's inspector. normally there is a script error caused by that code or code later on conflicting with your code there

if there is a conflict try this as it's using jQuery only and clear once is already in a closure so it should not have conflicted

```
(function($){
      'use strict';
      $(document).ready(function(){    
        // Your code goes here    
            var clearedOnce = false;
            $("#telid01").on("focus", function () {
                if (clearedOnce == false) {
                    this.value = '';
                    clearedOnce = true;
                }
            });
        });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
```

Comment: According to the console there are no errors, here is the full code:

Comment: Updated so if your using jQuery again you should not conflict with it

Comment: Thank you very much Martin, im going to try it out.

Comment: 2 Versions of jQuery when you call noConflict you force jQuery to return it and prevent jQuery from loading again and adding functions that already exist i'm not query sure how jquery does it but i think on first call to `jQuery()` it sets itself up so you call noConflict it does not re-setup the functions that are already there

Answer (score 1):

> `document.getElementById("telid01").onfocus`

If you're trying to use jQuery, you're doing it wrong. If you don't access elements with the $ selector, you aren't dealing with jQuery objects. You're dealing with straigt DOM objects. Correct that before trying to figure out what's wrong with jQuery.

You should be using:

```
 $('#telid01').on('focus', function() {...})
```

Comment: @Algorista: "It doesn't work" isn't a meaningful description of the problem.  What is the new state of your code?  What error or unexpected behavior are you seeing?  When you step through in a debugger, where and how does it fail?

Comment: It doesn't do what its supposed to do which is clearing my textbox when i click on it.

Comment: Dude. We're not here to write code for you, we're here to help you learn so you can do it yourself.

Comment: I know i'm just saying it doesn't work, you are right it didn't have the correct syntax. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is conflict with another library using the same `$` sign. Try replacing your JS code above with this one and see what happens:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){    
    // Your code goes here    
        var clearedOnce = false;
        document.getElementById("telid01").onfocus = 
        function () {
            if (clearedOnce == false) {
                this.value = '';
                clearedOnce = true;
            }
        };
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: It works but the rest of the site doesn't but i think that is because im including jQuery again.